# An application of the Central Limit Theorem to find an upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be iid random variables with $EX_i=\mu, \rm{Var}(X_i)=\sigma^2$. Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then by the Central Limit Theorem,
$$P\left(\frac{S_n-n\mu}{\sqrt{n}}\leq z\right)\to \Phi(z/\sigma)$$

> I am wondering if there exists a constant $C$, which does not depend on $z$ and such that $C\Phi(z/\sigma)<1$, such that $$P\left(\frac{S_n-n\mu}{\sqrt{n}}\leq z\right)\leq C\Phi(z/\sigma)$$ for all $n$.

I am thinking this is true, and I wanted to confirm if that's indeed the case. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Berry-Esseen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) helps quantify the rate of convergence.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks, that is good to know! Do you know of any other rate of convergence results better than that? I am seeking an upper bound of some constant times $\Phi$, rather than a constant plus $\Phi$. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this should be possible for $n=1$ if you can arrange the probability mass discretely. Check what happens if $X$ permits values $\pm x_0$, $x_0>0$ each with probability $p$ and $X=0$ with probability $1-2p$. I get $\mu =0$ and $\sigma = x_0\sqrt{2p}$, and $p/\Phi(-1/\sqrt{2p})$ is unbounded for small $p$

Comment: I think the idea generalizes for small $n$ and distributions for $X$ that have small concentrated off-center masses with a large central mass. The normal approximation is necessarily a very bad underestimate for values between the small left peak and the center

Comment: @Barri In your example, may I know what $p/\Phi(-1/\sqrt{2p})$ stands for? I am guessing you are considering the case, $z=-x_0$.

Comment: Yes, $p$ is the LHS of your inequality and the denominator is the factor on the RHS multiplying $C$

Comment: @Barri I see, that is a good example, thanks. I agree that the normal approximation would be bad for such distributions. I guess I should try to find an upper bound for large enough $n$, as opposed to all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: @Barri I see, yes, that sounds reasonable following your previous example. It would be good to know the conditions (may be for large $n$) under which the inequality does hold true.

Comment: I deleted my previous bc the expressions were off... I meant that the inequality reduces, for arbitrary finite $n$, to $p^re^{1/p}\leq C$ for some finite $r$, and for all $C>0$ there is some left tail probability $p$ where the inequality fails. I think such a bound can only work in some interval $(-z, z)$, not on the whole real line, even for large $n$

Comment: @Barri I see, but by CLT, the convergence happens for all $z$. So, for large $n$, the probability on LHS, $p$, should be close to $\Phi(z/\sigma)$ for all $z$, correct? So, intuitively, the ratio $p/\Phi(z/\sigma)$ cannot be unbounded for any $z$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is confusion about the convergence statement for 'large' but finite $n$. Take, for example, the $X$ distribution $$p(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}(1+x^2)^{-2}$$ which has mean $0$ and variance $1$. The convergence statement is, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n$ such that $\left|P(\bar S_n\leq z)-\Phi(z) \right|<\epsilon$ in some norm. This does not imply that the ratio $\frac{P(\bar S_n\leq z)}{\Phi(z)}$ is bounded for any finite $n$ for all $z$ on the real line. (I apologize, I know I did not define $\bar S_n=S_n/\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{n}\hat \mu$, Andrew's comment clarifies.)

Asymptotically, for the example distribution, up to constants (that depend on $n$, but not $z$), $P(\bar S_n\leq z)\sim \frac{1}{|z|^{3n}}$ and $\Phi(z)\sim \frac{e^{-z^2/2}}{|z|}$. These come from the leading terms in the Laurent series expansion of the CDF $\int_{-\infty}^z{p_X(t) dt}$ near $z=-\infty$. I am using the generous lower bound $(P(X_i\leq z\sqrt{n}))^n \leq P(\bar S_n\leq z)$. You can check these expressions [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+from+-inf+to+z+%281%2Bx%5E2%29%5E-2+expansion+near+-inf) for the sample distribution and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+e%5E%28-x%5E2%2F2%29+from+-inf+to+z+expand+at+-inf) for the normal approximation. So for every $n$, the ratio is unbounded as $z\to - \infty$.

Convergence implies that the interval in which such a bound holds can be made arbitrarily large. But unfortunately it is never the whole line for any finite $n$. The 'closeness' guaranteed by the CLT is as the norm of the difference, which does not translate to a bound in the ratio.

Comment: Just to clarify, the central limit theorem says that $$\sup_{t\in \mathbb R} |P(\sqrt n(\hat \mu-\mu)\leq t)-\Phi(t)|\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$where $\hat \mu$ is the sample mean. This, however, is not strong enough to deduce $$\sup_{t\in \mathbb R}\left \lvert \frac{P(\sqrt n(\hat \mu-\mu)\leq t)}{\Phi(t)}-1\right\rvert \underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Comment: Thank you, that is much more precise. I used $\bar S_n$ for the expression in the $P$ and convergence 'in some norm', which is vague

Comment: If I'm analyzing the asymptotics correctly, I don't think it's even strong enough to deduce $\sup_{t\in \mathbb R}\left \lvert \frac{P(\sqrt n(\hat \mu-\mu)\leq t)}{\Phi(t)}\right\rvert \underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} C<\infty$

Comment: See the edits for links to the expansions in Wolfram. You are thinking of the density function $p_N(z)\sim e^{-z^2/2}$. The CDF is the integral of $p(z')$ from $-\infty$ to $z$. But yes, the extra $z^{-1}$ does not affect the limit

Comment: @Barri yes, the Barry Essen theorem says that $P(\sqrt n(\hat \mu-\mu)\leq t)= \Phi(t)+O(1/\sqrt n)$. Of course then the issue is that in general, $\sup_t [\Phi(t)+O(1/\sqrt n)]/ \Phi(t) =\infty$